# Creating .resx files with ReSharper

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

So quite often I will add a line to my code `GetLocalResourceObject("Para1")` and then press `Alt-Enter` to have ReSharper first create the .resx file (on the first go) and then again to have it generate the line.

My pet peeve: it always opens the .resx file in it's XML view, which sometimes is OK but a lot of the time I end up having to find the file and open it in the resource editor view. Is there a way to have ReSharper instead open the .resx file in the resource editor view by default?

Comment: It isn't actually a solution to your problem, but the shortcut SHIFT-ALT-L (locate in solution explorer) would make locating the resx file less troublesome than finding it manually (if that is what you're doing)

Comment: Yeh I use that at the moment when I need to open the file in the editor view, it definitely helps find it quicker than navigating to it manually!